# Helm chart overriding values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

There is such structure of the project, I'm trying to understand:

```
charts/
  spark-0.0.1-100.tgz  
templates/
Chart.yaml
values.yaml
```

**Chart.yaml**

```
appVersion: 0.1.0
dependencies:
- name: spark
  version: "0.0.1-100"
  repository: https://helm.<corporation>.com/<project>
  condition: spark.enabled
```

**values.yaml** (some values are omitted for simplicity)

```
spark:
  enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/spark-service-account
  image:
    tag: "3.3.0-dev-28"
  extraEnv:
  - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
    value: regional
  Master:
    Requests:
      Cpu: ...
      Memory: ...
      Disk: ...
    Limits:
      Cpu: ...
      Memory: ...
      Disk: ...
  Worker:
    Replicas: 3
    Requests:
      Cpu: ...
      Memory: ...
      Disk: ...
    Limits:
      Cpu: ...
      Memory: ...
      Disk: ...
  zookeeper:
    host: "project-zookeeper"
    port: 2181
```

Then, I have unzipped `charts/spark-0.0.1-100.tgz` into folder `charts/spark/`:

```
charts/
  spark/
    templates/
    Chart.yaml
    values.yaml
```

**charts/spark/values.yaml**:

```
global:
  aci:
    sdrAppname: spark

image:
  repository: "docker.<corporation>.com/<project>/spark"
  tag: "1.0.1"

spark:
  path: "/opt/spark"
  user: 1000
  group: 1000
  config: |
    SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=21600"

Master:
  Name: master
  Replicas: 1
  Component: "spark-core"
  Requests:
    Cpu: ...
    Memory: ...
    Disk: ...
  Limits:
    Cpu: ...
    Memory: ...
    Disk: ...
  ServicePort: <port>
  ContainerPort: <port>
  RestEnabled: "true"
  RestPort: <port>
  ServiceType: LoadBalancer

WebUi:
  Name: webui
  ServicePort: <port>
  ContainerPort: <port>
```

The question is, how values from `values.yaml` and `charts/spark/values.yaml` are being corresponded?
Are values from root `values.yaml` are replaced with values from `charts/spark/values.yaml`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, how values from values.yaml and charts/spark/values.yaml are being corresponded?

The short version is they have *almost* nothing to do with one another, they're just the defaults used by their respective charts. The medium version is that the outer chart can [supersede values in the subordinate charts](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart) if it *chooses* to, but ultimately the user has the final word in that discussion because `helm --values` win out over the defaults (same for usage of `--set`, but `--values` are far easier to discuss due to not having to delve into that `--set` DSL)

The subcharts are not aware of the parent chart's defaults. The parent chart doesn't *have* to be aware of the child chart's values, and cannot -- itself -- refer to the subchart's defaults

> Are values from root values.yaml are replaced with values from charts/spark/values.yaml?

For the most part, no, they're completely separate namespaces. However, as we saw above, for every `- name:` key in the `dependencies:` list, those top-level keys in the parent chart's values.yaml becomes special in that it overlays the values on top of the subordinate chart's defaults (you see in your example of `{ spark: { path: "/opt/spark" } }`; that top level `spark:` key matches up with `- name:` in the `dependencies:` list)

It's kind of like "duck typing" though, because the top level key is free to use any random structure and the child chart will use ones that it is aware of. For example:

```yaml
# values.yaml
spark:
  path: /opt/spark
  value-of-pi: 3.1415
```

is perfectly legal in the top chart's values.yaml even though the child spark chart will only notice the `{ spark: { path: "" } }` because it does not have any `{{ .Values.value-of-pi }}` in its templates

But, again, for clarity: the top level values.yaml, even if it includes `spark: { path: /alpha }` can be superseded by the user with `--values <(echo '{spark: {path: /beta } }')` and the resulting spark install will have `path: /beta` when that chart is templated out